# What is the difference between a Gaussian random walk and a Gauss-Markov process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, random-walk

My understanding is as follows:

- A Gaussian random walk is a Markov process $X_0,X_1,\ldots$, where $X_0$ has a Gaussian probability density function (PDF) and for $n=1,2,\ldots$, given $X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}$, $X_n$ has a Gaussian conditional PDF with mean equal to $x_{n-1}$.
- A Gauss-Markov process is a random process that is both a Gaussian process and a Markov process.

What is the difference between them? Are there Gauss-Markov processes that are not Gaussian random walks?

Comment: 1) Continuous time processes exist. 2) Is a gaussian random walk even necessarily a gaussian process? At least to me, this isn't a priori obvious. 3) consider e.g. ornstein uhlenbeck restricted to integer times. It has transition semigroup $$\mu_t(x,dy) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-e^{-2t})}}\exp\left(\frac{-|y-e^{-t}x|^2}{2(1-e^{-2t})}\right)\,dy,\quad t>0$$

Comment: @Andrew 1) Noted. 2) Here is my intuition. If PDFs $f_{X_0}$ and $f_{X_1|X_0}$ are both Gaussian, then $f_{X_0,X_1}$ with $f_{X_0,X_1}(x_0,x_1)=f_{X_0}(x_0)f_{X_1|X_0}(x_1|x_0)$ is also Gaussian, hence $X_0,X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are jointly Gaussian for any positive integer $n$. 3) How is that Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process related to Gauss-Markov processes?

Comment: The ornstein uhlenbeck process is (essentially) the only stationary gauss markov process